# How to create dynamic array and variable in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically create as many variables as the number of color data read from json and assign the same color values ​​to the created variables.

For example; 
 blue colors dynamically incoming variable
 red colors dynamically incoming variable
 green colors dynamically incoming variable

then I want to store them in different dynamic arrays

```
{

    "color": "red"
},  
{

    "color": "red"
},  
{

    "color": "green"
}, 
{

    "color": "blue"
}
```

```
function datareadd(latitude, longitude, number) {
  $.getJSON("json.json", function(dataa) {
    var markers = [];
    var renkler = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
      markers[i] = [];
      console.log(markers);
    }
    let grup = dataa.reduce((r, a) => {
      r[a.color] = [...r[a.color] || [], a];
      return r;
    }, renkler);

    console.log(grup.blue);
  })
}
datareadd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you want to achieve like below.

```js
var dataa = [{
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "color": "blue"
  }
];

var grup = dataa.map(x => ({ [x.color]: x.color }));

console.log(grup);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer why i want to keep the resulting color values ​​in different arrays automatically

Comment: What is your expected output array look like? Like this `[ { "red" : "red" }, { "green" : "green" }, { "blue" : "blue" } ]`. But for array you will not be able to get value like `grup.blue`.

Comment: yes I want it to look like this ```[ { "red" : "red" }, { "green" : "green" }, { "blue" : "blue" } ]```